# cocos2d spaceship targets enemies, then shoots in order

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, side-scroller

Im using cocos2d version 3 in Xcode.

I want to move a sprite to a number of touch locations, in the order they were touched. It'll be a different number each time.

With TouchBegan I've added sprites that look like targets at the touch locations, and saved them as objects in an array. I've initialized the array and it's working fine.

I need to move a sprite to the first objects location, then the second, third etc. I'm nearly there but can't find a way to 'cycle through' the array to get the locations. I can only get the first location by setting up a CCNode as objectAtIndex:0 and using the nodePosition.

This is asking a lot, but I've googled for days and I can't find anything! Been on this for days!

Comment: What you said sounds fine. Give it a go! Best way to learn is to try.

Comment: Did you read this -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial. It's a great tutorial for starters

Comment: Hi Troveldom. I've followed a few of his tutorials. Very useful. I've got quite far with my game. I know about schedulers, CCActions, most of the basics etc.

Comment: I can make it work if I know the number of objects in the array: I just create a node for each object. But in the game, it's user input so it'll be a different number each time :/

Comment: On each TouchBegan you add the touch position to a pendingDestinations array and when you reach a destination you just pop the first destination and continue to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example on: http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial

You can use the following code to go to each point:

```
// 4
CCActionMoveTo *actionMove   = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5f position:targetPosition];
CCActionRemove *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
[theSprite runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];
```

And when you reach the target point just add the following target

Comment: My problem is in getting each array objects location, and then using them one by one in a CCAction. If the array always had 5 objects, I could create a node for each object and use CCActionSequence to 'visit' them all. But because the number of objects is changeable, I can't lock down an action to a specific number.

Comment: But you can store the touch locations in a mutable array and use the array to set the targets, once you reach the first, you just pop it out of the array and lock the action to the next one.

Comment: I couldn't add CGPoints to the muteableArray, which is why I added target sprites. Thought I could then get the locations afterwards and use them in an action.

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: When I visit a location, pop it out of the array kinda like: [myArray removeObject objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why is it that you couldn't add the points to the mutableArray?

Comment: Apparently CGPoint isn't an object. Saw a post about using NSValue as a wrapper. Will give that a try! What do you think of this logic:

Comment: Use [Array count] to get the number of objects in array. Create an action sequence to move the sprite to objectAtIndex:0, then remove objectAtIndex:0. Then, repeat the sequence by the Array count.